# C# - Better way to pass in <key, value> pairs to create JProperty objects

Tags: c#, json, json.net, log4net

My log4net object looks something like this (since I want to log my set as a json object)

```
_log.Debug(new JObject(new JProperty("Prop1", "Val1"),
                       new JProperty("Prop2", "Val2")).ToString());
```

For better code readability and easy adding of additional properties, I'd like to do something like this

```
Utility.WriteLog({"Prop1", "Val1"}, 
                 {"Prop2", "Val2"});
```

I am not sure how the WriteLog() method would look like other than that it should have a params argument considering that there will be a variable number of property/value pairs that need to be logged.

I have considered a dictionary (see below) and the WriteLog function would create a JsonObject with the property/value keys from the dictionary:

```
Utility.WriteLog(new Dictionary<string, string>()
                        {
                            {"Prop1", "Val1"}, 
                            {"Prop2", "Val2" }
                        });
```

Is this the best approach, or is there a more succinct alternative?

Comment: What version of c# are you using?

Comment: What's the problem with your initial version?

Comment: If you are using c# 7.0 or later you could use abbreviated Tuple syntax, e.g. `public static void WriteLog(params (string Name, object Value) [] parameters)` and then call it like `Utility.WriteLog(("Prop1", "Val1"), ("Prop2", "Val2"));`.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/cxRnmY.  Is that what you want?  Your question is kind of subjective.

Comment: And in c# 9.0 you could use `new () { {"Prop1", "Val1"}, {"Prop2", "Val2" } } ` to construct your dictionary.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/cxRnmY again.

Comment: @Alejandro - If you mean the one with the new JProperty() calls, it's exactly that i.e. Instantiating a JObject and adding JProperty values for every logging step.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using c# 7.0 or later, you could use the [simplified tuple syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#tuples-and-discards) to pass in a `params` array of name/value [tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples) for formatting via serialization and subsequent logging.

Since you have tagged your question [log4net](/questions/tagged/log4net), you could define extension methods on `ILog` like so:

```
public static partial class LogExtensions
{
    public static void DebugProperties(this ILog log, params (string Name, object Value) [] parameters)
        // TODO: handle duplicate Name keys in some graceful manner.
        => log.Debug(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parameters.ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.Value), Formatting.Indented));
    
    public static void InfoProperties(this ILog log, params (string Name, object Value) [] parameters)
        => log.Info(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parameters.ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.Value), Formatting.Indented));
}
```

And then call them like:

```
log.DebugProperties(("Prop1", "Val1"), ("Prop2", "Val2"));
log.InfoProperties(("Prop3", new SomeClass { SomeValue = "hello" }));
```

And get the output:

```
2021-01-21 21:12:36,215 DEBUG: {
  "Prop1": "Val1",
  "Prop2": "Val2"
}
2021-01-21 21:12:36,230 INFO : {
  "Prop3": {
    "SomeValue": "hello"
  }
}
```

If you are using c# 9.0 or later, you could also add a logging method taking a `Dictionary<string, object>` and, when calling the method, use the [abbreviated `new ()` syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#fit-and-finish-features) which omits the type when already known:

```
public static partial class LogExtensions
{
    public static void DebugDictionary(this ILog log, Dictionary<string, object> parameters)
        => log.Debug(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parameters, Formatting.Indented));
}
```

And then later:

```
log.DebugDictionary(new () { {"Prop1", "Val1"}, {"Prop2", "Val2" } } );
```

Of course, if you prefer you could wrap your `ILog log` in a `Utility` class with methods whose inputs are like those of the extension methods above, but it isn't necessary if you use extension methods.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/12SymX).